# Matlab: using user input to access cellarray data

Tags: matlab, input, simulation

I am trying to use input from user to access the contant of a specific cell. However, the format seems to be always incorrect.

```
function CountParticlesNew(L,M,N)
pos = input("Indica coordinate voxel nel formato x,y,z: ");
coordlist = cell(1,N);
for counter = 1:N
coordlist{counter} = L*rand(1,3);
end
step = L/M;
positlist=cell(M,M,M);
for counter = 1:N
cellarray = coordlist{counter};
checkx = cellarray(1,1);
checky = cellarray(1,2);
checkz = cellarray(1,3);
posx = 1;
posy = 1;
posz = 1;
for counterx = step:step:checkx
    posx = posx+1;
end
for countery = step:step:checky
    posy = posy+1;
end
for counterz = step:step:checkz
    posz = posz+1;
end
checkempty = isempty(positlist{posx,posy,posz});
if checkempty == 1
    positlist{posx,posy,posz} = 1;
else
    positlist{posx,posy,posz} = 
positlist{posx,posy,posz}+1;
end
end
display = positlist{pos};
disp(display)
end
```

As you can see I am trying to get a input "pos" to thn initialize "display" to a specific cell and then display it with disp(), however it doesn't work. Any help?

EDIT:

here are some errors as I try to access cell with indexes 1,1,1:

> `1,1,1`

```
Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or
unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error. To construct matrices, use brackets
instead of parentheses.
```

> `(1,1,1)`

```
Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use
parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters.
```

> `{1,1,1}`

```
Unable to use a value of type cell as an index.

Error in test (line 33)
display = positlist{pos};
```

If I try to display `pos` I only get a result if I input `{1,1,1}`, which is

`{[1]}    {[1]}    {[1]}`

Comment: Did you look at what the variable `pos` contains after you type in your response to the `input` function? What does “it doesn’t work” mean? Please copy-paste any error messages, or describe clearly what you observe and how that differs from your expectations.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I will add right now some examples in my posts

Comment: `input` evaluates the expression, so you need to enter something that is a valid MATLAB expression, such as `[1,1,1]` or `{1,1,1}`. But if you add `'s'` as the 2nd argument to `input`, it will just take the string you type as input. That might be the more elegant approach, but then you need to figure out how to translate that string into a set of indices into the array, which will not be trivial. The simplest solution would be to have 3 `input` statements, one for each dimension, so that you can just type a single number for each.